# Some proposals does not increase 1% when I commit, but when I do Uncommit -> Follow -> UnFollow -> Commit Again Its got increased 1%?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Some proposals does not increase 1% when I commit, but when I do Uncommit -> Follow -> UnFollow -> Commit Again Its got increased 1%

Intentional or Am I just discover some hacks?

<sub>**Note**: I tried it on "Apocalyptic Defense" and one other, now I uncommited both.</sub>

Comment: Did you refresh the page after committing the first time?

Comment: @emmett, yes, I think I did 2 or 3 times after first commit.

Comment: Mark The commitment score is recalculated every time someone commits or uncommits. Assuming nobody else committed between your first and second commitments, I'm not sure what's going on here. Please report back if you observe this behavior again.

Comment: @emmett, now percentage does not increase anymore, even I do follow->unfollow->commit many times. I've tried it in "food and cooking". Is that mean someone fixed it not to be happened?

Comment: Here, have an arrow: **→**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe the commit change depends on either the current percentage, or the rep of other users that have committed.

I just committed to White Hat SEO and it jumped from 5% to 7%. I committed to Web Applications and it stayed on 90%.

Comment: FYI, 90% is the current maximum, as they're not ready for launching sites into beta yet.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case. It seems that quite a few are between 90% and 100% now (but without actual beta sites yet).